Why transaction is not closed?
There is a problem using EntityListener when it occurs error.
The scenario is as follows:

UserService save user entity
PostUpdateEventListener throws Exception
I query SELECT ... FOR UPDATE on database

Then the query was pending until I killed.
I think when PostUpdateEventListener throws Exception, database transaction is not be commit/rollback.
Do you know why this happened? And Is the only way to avoid using PostUpdateEventListener not throw exception?
Below is example code

user service

     @Transactional
     fun save(): User {
         val user = userRepository.findByIdOrNull(1)!!
         user.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now()
         return userRepository.save(user)
     }


EntityUpdateEventListener


@Component
class EntityUpdateEventListener(
     private val logService: LogService;
) : PostUpdateEventListener {
     override fun onPostUpdate(
         event: PostUpdateEvent
     ) {
         throwException()
     }
    
     override fun requiresPostCommitHanding(persister: EntityPersister?): Boolean = false
}


HibernateListenerConfig

@Component
class HibernateListenerConfig(
     private val entityUpdateEventListener: EntityUpdateEventListener
) {
     @PersistenceUnit
     private val emf: EntityManagerFactory? = null

     @PostConstruct
     private fun init() {
         val sessionFactory = emf!!.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl::class.java)
         val registry = sessionFactory.serviceRegistry.getService(
             EventListenerRegistry::class.java
         )

         registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(entityUpdateEventListener)
     }
}


Log

2024-04-03 15:25:30.774 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [...UserService.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2024-04-03 15:25:30.775 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1290086990<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-04-03 15:25:30.776 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
2024-04-03 15:25:30.776 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2024-04-03 15:25:30.779 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@4f409583]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.779 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [...UserService.save]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.781 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1290086990<open>)] for JPA transaction
2024-04-03 15:25:30.781 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2024-04-03 15:25:30.781 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.789 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] h.e.i.EntityCopyObserverFactoryInitiator : Configured EntityCopyObserver strategy: disallow
2024-04-03 15:25:30.805 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Static select for action ACTION_MERGE on entity ...models.User: select user0_.id as id1_38_0_, user0_.created_at as created_2_38_0_, user0_.updated_at as updated_3_38_0_, ...
2024-04-03 15:25:30.805 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Loading entity: [...models.User#6]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.805 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_38_0_, user0_.created_at as created_2_38_0_, user0_.updated_at as updated_3_38_0_, ...
2024-04-03 15:25:30.806 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [6]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.809 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2024-04-03 15:25:30.810 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[...models.User#6]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.810 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [...models.User#6]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.810 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `createdAt` : value = 2024-03-18T09:50:03
2024-04-03 15:25:30.810 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`createdAt`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
...
2024-04-03 15:25:30.811 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [...models.User#6]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.811 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Done entity load
2024-04-03 15:25:30.813 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.813 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [...UserService.save]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.813 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2024-04-03 15:25:30.814 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1290086990<open>)]
2024-04-03 15:25:30.814 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2024-04-03 15:25:30.814 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2024-04-03 15:25:30.814 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2024-04-03 15:25:30.820 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 1 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2024-04-03 15:25:30.820 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2024-04-03 15:25:30.821 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2024-04-03 15:25:30.821 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : ...models.User{...}
2024-04-03 15:25:30.831 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update users set created_at=?, updated_at=? where id=?
2024-04-03 15:25:30.832 TRACE 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2024-03-18T09:50:03]
...
2024-04-03 15:25:30.837 DEBUG 93850 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1290086990<open>)] after transaction
java.lang.Exception
    at ...EntityUpdateEventListener.isScheduledMethodInvoked(EntityUpdateEventListener.kt:22)
    ...
2024-04-03 15:25:41.715 DEBUG 93850 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
2024-04-03 15:25:41.715 DEBUG 93850 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.

I am using this version.

spring boot 2.6.6
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.6.6
kotlin 1.6.10
java 17

I can fix it by using try/catch in EntityListenter. But I want to know why transaction is not closed by error in EntityListener or Why is this happened.
Please help me, thanks!
